# React, API, Fetch. Как через имеющееся API вывести данные на страницу?

Tags: reactjs, api

React, API, Fetch. Хочу через имеющееся API вывести данные на страницу, но не получается. Не пойму что не так.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ProductCardBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`http://wow.kg/crm/api/?action=view&object=api_products`, {mode: "no-cors"})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => { 
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json.api_products,
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        let {isLoaded, items} = this.state;

        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading... </div>
        } else {
            return (
                <ul>
                   {items.map(item => (
                       <li key={item.id}>
                         {item.title}
                       </li>
                   ))}
                </ul>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в консоли выводится вот такая ошибка  - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: С вашим кодом всё впорядке ‍⚕️Ошибка означает что с сервера приезжает невалидный JSON.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. :)) Будем разбираться.

Comment: @Nurilya в ошибке на самом деле все написано. Происходит функция JSON.parse(response.json() вот это вызывает JSON.parse).  Непредвиденное окончание json на первое линии в первое колонке. Т.е  таким образом он говорит, что пришла фигня и он не знает, что с этим делать(не валидный)

Comment: Скрипт же вам в консоли скорей всего пишет _Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://wow.kg/crm/api/?action=view&object=api_products. (Причина: заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin» не совпадает с «https://wow.kg»)._ Запрещено политикой. браузер получает `json`, (это видно в инструментах браузера), но браузер не отдает его fetch'у, вылетает ошибка

Answer (score 0):

```
Вобщем, в итоге пришлось делать вот так. 

 componentDidMount() {
        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const url = "http://wow.kg/crm/api/?action=view&object=api_products&id=223"; 
        fetch(proxyurl + url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => { 
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json.api_products
            })
        })
        .catch(() => console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?"))

    }
```